# Partial search through a SQL database efficiently

Tags: java, c#, sql

What are some examples of efficiently searching through a directory as you're typing a person's name?

Say for example, we have a database with 1 million users. We start typing in the search box: "sea", it will display every user's name on a scroll-able window that has "sea" on it (kind of like searching through a Skype directory). After changing a letter, the window should update immediately. All of this is coming from a SQL database. What are few efficient libraries, algorithms that can do this without much delay?

Comment: This is off-topic, please see [help/dont-ask]. If you have a specific problem, post relevant code and it will be possible to help you.

Comment: Don't need any library or fancy algorithm.  Just make sure that the table has an index on the column that you're searching on, then do an ordinary SQL select.

Answer (score 1):

First consider changing the task from "name contains substring" to "name starts with substring". If this is possible, then add index on your **name** column in database table and use the query:

```
select name from table where name like :1 || '%'
```

Limit the number of returned rows using DBMS-specific syntax, for example, for Oracle add

```
and rownum < 20
```

This query should return your rows pretty fast.

If you really need "contains substring", then decide whether you want the search to be handled by database or by an external text indexing solution.

For database-contained solution you'll have to use a different approach depending on DBMS. Every one of these solutions requires configuration steps not described here.

For Oracle you can use Oracle Text, see

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/index-098492.html

The query will look like

```
select name from table where contains(name, :1) > 0
```

For Postgres you can use Full Text Search.

You can also use a solution that is not dependent on the database, for example, see Apache Solr:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: Wouldn't be something like "select name from table where name >= :1" be more efficient? Maybe Oracle optmizes your "%" in these cases, but I believe that my solution would work on a larger selection of versions/products.

Comment: Unfortunately, that query returns incorrect result. Consider a record 'abc' stored in table and input value 'abb'. The record should NOT be returned, but it would be when using your condition.

Comment: you are absolutely right, my example was wrong, even if the point was still valid, I think. Let's try again. "select name from table where name >= :1 and name <:2" where the second variable should be "first variable+highest printable character" so if :1 is "abb" the query should become  "select name from table where name >= 'abb' and name <'abbZ'" - note also that it would be more effective to build ":2" as a variable instead of writing "select name from table where name >= :1 and name <:1+'Z'".

Comment: @p.marino this seems like a valid solution. It also seems to be more reliable for wider range of DBMSs. However, you'll have to think of the highest printable character.

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
SELECT name
FROM Table
WHERE name LIKE '%sea%'
```

Comment: And also use TextChange Event if I am not mistaken.

Comment: This is highly inefficient and will kill the server.

Comment: Then add WITH READPAST.

Comment: READPAST will do nothing to solve the performance problem. Clearly you are oblivious to the impact of table scanning 1 million rows multiple times in quick succession.

Comment: Ok I got your point. Then do not use TextChange :) Just create a search button instead.